Book in which the main character is a female wizard who can read minds
I think the main character started as a young girl, but may have switched to a guy's perspective at times.
She was a wizard, and when learning the magic process, she was taught that she had to visualize or process every step of making a cake before it would form.
I think in the first book she gets attacked and bit by a spider thing that's poisonous in a tower, so when the guy carries her, she ends up talking to him telepathically because the poison makes her unable to speak.
They have to learn how to block telepathic stuff from bad guys.
Later they get married.
At one point, the main character is testing her telepathy and looks into the mind of the lady leading her while she reads a book. The lady gets mad since she did it without asking.

In roughly which year did you read this? Also, do you recall how many books there were in the series?

I read it like 5-6 years ago, and I feel like it could be a trilogy. I rented it from my church library, so it might have some christian values, but not sure. I think it might have had some things with portals as well, where they had to repair them with threads of light...

Wild Magic involves a young girl falling in love with her wizard teacher, but get gift is with animals (and immortals), not humans.

I dont think that's it, but thanks

I think the story you're describing is DragonQuest, book 2 of the DragonKeeper Chronicles by Donita K. Paul. The first book in the series is more of a solo adventure with the protagonist Kale, and it's not until this book that we meet most of the other characters and the world gets fleshed out, so a lot of it feels like the first book in a series.

She was a wizard, and when learning the magic process, she was taught that she had to visualize or process every step of making a cake before it would form.

In the chapter "Lesson One", Kale has just started her lessons with the wizard Fenworth. Fenworth has her and the other apprentices bake a cake through mundane means, then the first magic they do is creating new cakes by closing their eyes and visualizing the entire process, from mixing the batter to the cake cooking in the oven.

I think in the first book she gets attacked and bit by a spider thing that's poisonous in a tower, so when the guy carries her, she ends up talking to him telepathically because the poison makes her unable to speak.

In the chapter "Attack!", Kale is attacked by a giant Creemoor spider and is poisoned. In the next chapter, "Poison", she is carried out of a tower by Bardon, and because her tongue is too swollen to speak she talks to him telepathically (called "mindspeaking" in universe).

I read it like 5-6 years ago, and I feel like it could be a trilogy.

The first book (DragonSpell) was published in 2004, and the last book in the pentalogy (DragonLight) was published in 2008.

I rented it from my church library, so it might have some christian values, but not sure.

Donita K. Paul is a Christian fantasy author, and the story has many Christian thematic elements. The wizards teach that the world is ordered because God made it so, and there is a Christ figure named Paladin.

Yes! Thank you!
